# Split on roman numbers using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a text on the roman numbers.
Here is my text

```
This is the part (a) of question number one. i. This is sub part one of part (a) question one ii. This is sub part two of part (a) question one iii. This is sub part three of part (a) question one
```

Actually this is one part in a question of a question paper.How ever I wanted it to be broken down as follows.

```
This is the part (a) of question number one.
This is sub part one of part (a) question one
This is sub part two of part (a) question one
This is sub part three of part (a) question one
```

So in here What I want is, divided the sentence on roman numbers.
Here is my the regular expression I have written

```
text = This is the part (a) of question number one. i. This is sub part one of part (a) question one ii. This is sub part two of part (a) question one iii. This is sub part three of part (a) question one
for m in re.split(r' [a-z]+\. ',text):
    print(m)
```

This is what I get

```
This is the part (a) of question number one.
i. This is sub part one of part (a) question one
This is sub part two of part (a) question one
This is sub part three of part (a) question one
```

My expression worked on roman number two and three but not on roman number one.
So I need a general expression which suit for any roman number.
Important thing to be noted is that before a roman number there is a space and after a roman number there is a full stop and then a space.
Can some help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression captures substring `one.`, try to change it in this way:

```
text = 'This is the part (a) of question number one. i. This is sub part one of part (a) question one ii. This is sub part two of part (a) question one iii. This is sub part three of part (a) question one'

for m in re.split(r' [MDCLXVI]+\. ', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    print(m)
```

Comment: Wow..It is worked fine..Can you tell me what is the wrong with my code..?

Comment: @Punuth your regular expression was also capturing substring ` one. `.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what I get.  Check your first line again.  I get

```
This is the part (a) of question number
```

and that because your regex matches "one."

```
re.split(r'i+\. ',text)
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *proper* romanette numbers (roman numerals in lower case are often refer to as 'romanette'), they are easily generated. Mark Pilgrim has a variety of Roman Numeral utilities in the book *Dive Into Python* some of which can be seen [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/utils/roman.py).

The one that that generates man numerals:

```
class RomanError(Exception): pass
class OutOfRangeError(RomanError): pass
class NotIntegerError(RomanError): pass
class InvalidRomanNumeralError(RomanError): pass

def toRoman(n):
    """convert integer to Roman numeral"""
    if not (0 < n < 5000):
        raise OutOfRangeError, "number out of range (must be 1..4999)"
    if int(n) != n:
        raise NotIntegerError, "decimals can not be converted"
    romanNumeralMap = (('M',  1000), ('CM', 900), ('D',  500), ('CD', 400), ('C',  100), ('XC', 90),
       ('L',  50), ('XL', 40), ('X',  10), ('IX', 9), ('V',  5), ('IV', 4), ('I',  1))
    result = ""
    for numeral, integer in romanNumeralMap:
        while n >= integer:
            result += numeral
            n -= integer
    return result
```

Test that:

```
>>> [toRoman(x) for x in range(1,21)]
['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XI', 'XII', 'XIII', 'XIV', 'XV', 'XVI', 'XVII', 'XVIII', 'XIX', 'XX']
```

That can be used to generate a pattern for all the roman numerals up to 20 and put that into a regex:

```
>>> pat=' (?:'+'|'.join([int_to_roman(i).lower() for i in range(1,21)])+')\. '
>>> pat
' (?:i|ii|iii|iv|v|vi|vii|viii|ix|x|xi|xii|xiii|xiv|xv|xvi|xvii|xviii|xix|xx)\\. '
```

Then you can split your text:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(re.split(pat, txt))
This is the part (a) of question number one.
This is sub part one of part (a) question one
This is sub part two of part (a) question one
This is sub part three of part (a) question one
```

Or, you can use [his regex](https://regex101.com/r/xJ9mU3/2) in `re.split`:

```
>>> pat=re.compile('''\
... [ ]                 # one space
... m{0,4}              # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
... (?:cm|cd|d?c{0,3})  # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
...                     #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
... (?:xc|xl|l?x{0,3})  # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
...                     #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
... (?:ix|iv|v?i{0,3})  # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
...                     #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
... [.][ ]                # full stop then a space''', re.X)
>>> print '\n'.join(pat.split(txt))
This is the part (a) of question number one.
This is sub part one of part (a) question one
This is sub part two of part (a) question one
This is sub part three of part (a) question one
```